# MySQL storing duration time - datatype?

Tags: mysql, time, types, duration

I need to calculate the time a user spends on site. It is difference between logout time and login time to give me something like "Mr X spent 4 hours and 43 minutes online". So to store the4 hours and 43 minutes i declared it like this:
`duration` time NOT NULL

Is this valid or a better way to store this? I need to store in the DB because I have other calculations I need to use this for + other use cases.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Storing it as an integer number of seconds will be the best way to go.

- The `UPDATE` will be clean and simple - i.e. `duration = duration + $increment`
- As Tristram noted, there are [limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) to using the `TIME` field - e.g. "`TIME` values may range from `'-838:59:59'` to `'838:59:59'`"
- The days/hours/minutes/seconds display formatting won't be hardcoded.
- The execution of your *other calculations* will almost surely be clearer when working with an integer "number of seconds" field.

Comment: I'd definitely go with `TIME`.  I can't think of anybody spending 34 days in a row online. If so, I'm ready to let this rare case run into an error. `UPDATE` statements can be easily done using `ADDTIME()`. With this you can also add like 30 minutes and 23 seconds without transferring that into seconds. Nothing is hardcoded, you can always do `TIME_TO_SEC()` – if you really need that (what I doubt).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use time as you would be limited to 24 hours. The easiest would just to store an integer in minutes (or seconds depending on the resolution you need).

Comment: integer wont give exact time like 4 hours, 45 minutes 32 seconds unless i store in seconds? I was hoping to auto format the entry directly inthe DB as x hours, x minutes. (maybe add x seconds too) instead of storing it as 474747474 seconds which then again requires conversion into a human readable form.

Comment: @Juds I'd argue that the convenience of having a formatted time interval in the DB is outweighed by the many other factors @Tristram and @Riedsio have mentioned. Why not let interval formatting be a presentation-layer concern? :)

Comment: time isn't limited to 24 hours, see above

Answer (score -3):

Consider storing both values as a UNIX-epoch-delta.

I generally prefer to use a signed (64b) bigint (for secondly resolution), or a (signed) (64b) double (if fractional seconds are needed), or a signed (32b) int (if scaled down to minutely or hourly).

Make the unit explicit in the name of the column, for example with a suffix like "_epoch_minutely", for example: "started_epoch_minutely", "finished_epoch_minutely".

Comment: ...not sure what you mean.  Is there some documentation on "`UNIX-epoch-delta`"? An example would also be helpful. Also, *Welcome to [so]!* (Check out [answer].)

Comment: A "UNIX-epoch-delta" is just the UNIX time() value, which is the number of seconds since the UNIX-epoch, which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: This is a bit pointless as it replicates exactly what the standard timestamp functionality built In to MySQL already does.