# MySQL how to add 2 times over 24:00 hours

Tags: mysql, time, addition

In MySQL I have two durations : 15:12 and 19:24 and I want to select the sum of them. This will exceed 24:00 hours. It doesn't seem to work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL storing duration time - datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498513/mysql-storing-duration-time-datatype)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ADDTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) to get the `SUM` of these two time values:

```
SELECT ADDTIME('15:12', '19:24') -- 34:36:00
```

To `SUM` multiple time values you can use the following solution:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(':', 
        SUBSTRING(CAST(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(x.t_value))) + 0 AS CHAR), 1, LENGTH(CAST(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(x.t_value))) + 0 AS CHAR)) - 4),
        SUBSTRING(CAST(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(x.t_value))) + 0 AS CHAR), -4, 2),
        SUBSTRING(CAST(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(x.t_value))) + 0 AS CHAR), -2, 2)
    )
FROM (
    SELECT '15:12' AS t_value UNION ALL
    SELECT '19:24' AS t_value UNION ALL
    SELECT '2:00' AS t_value
)x

-- 36:36:00
```