# Storing a duration in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time, database-design

I need to store durations such as the following in mysql:

```
- 30 seconds
- 20 minutes, 12 seconds
- 1 month
```

What would be the best way to store this, as the definition of a month can't be reduced, for example, to a number of seconds. My first thought was to store each increment separate, for example:

```
- num_seconds
- num_minutes
- num_hours
- num_days
- num_months
```

This could store the above, but I was hoping there was a more direct and less verbose way of doing this.

Comment: maybe by using linux timestamps? store two timestamps and you can get the seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, years out off it

Comment: The question is how you are going to *use* the results.  If you just need an interval for display purposes, a string is sufficient.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4498513

Comment: @RaymondNijland that might work for most cases, doing something like a normalized `anchor` and then `interval`.

Comment: Are the interval values restricted to the number range that they would normally use e.g. seconds = 0-59, hours=0-23 etc.?

Comment: The only exceptions are months and years. Anything from weeks and less can be represented as seconds. But as it was pointed out before, it's all about how you're going to use this. If it's going in a `DateTime::modify()` for example, you can simply store it as a string to be used as the second parameter for this method.

Comment: I assume you are not getting into leap-seconds, nor into milliseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your intervals for years to months as an integer counting the number of months (12 months = 1 year) and your intervals for days to seconds as an integer of number of seconds.

You can then use the `DATE_ADD` function to figure out your dates. Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e900c7/1) example showing storing intervals as months and seconds, and adding them to a fixed date:

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table mytab (dt date);
insert into mytab values (date '2018-01-01');

create table intervals (months int, seconds int);
insert into intervals values (13, 3661), (-13, -3661);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select dt
     , months
     , seconds
     , date_add(date_add(dt, interval months month)
                           , interval seconds second) result
  from mytab cross join intervals
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e900c7/1/0)**:

```
|         dt | months | seconds |               result |
|------------|--------|---------|----------------------|
| 2018-01-01 |     13 |    3661 | 2019-02-01T01:01:01Z |
| 2018-01-01 |    -13 |   -3661 | 2016-11-30T22:58:59Z |
```

Answer (score 2):

My first option would be to store duration as a number of seconds with datatype INT. This will make computation and comparison operations fast and clean. Also you can easily compute the duration between two datetime values, by substracting their Unix timestamp. When you need to display the values, you can use [mysql sec_to_time function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-sec_to_time-function.php) :

However if you are looking to manipulate big durations (months, years), this will not work. In that case I would fallback on a VARCHAR column with  [iso8601 duration format](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs//90001488-13/reference/r_iso_8601_duration_format.htm), like P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S for 3 years, 6 months, 4 days, 12 hours, 30 minutes and 5 seconds. It is a well known format that is supported by many applications (but will be more tedious to manipulate).

Comment: What would you use for months, since it depends on the starting date? And years depends on whether it's a leap year.

Comment: The question specifically says **the definition of a month can't be reduced, for example, to a number is seconds.**

Comment: @Barmar : yes, you are correct. I guess my answer was too fast... I gave the question a good second look and updated my answer.

Comment: This is better, but how will you use that ISO8601 duration in MySQL calculations? I don't think MySQL can use it directly.

Comment: @barmar, while MySQL can't handle the entire duration string in one go, you can split it  into year_month and day_second portions and use them with the date_add function: `date_add(mydate, interval 'P3Y6M' year_month) ` and `date_add(mydate, interval '4DT12H30M5S' day_second)` to do the whole thing nest it like in my answer.

Comment: @Sentinel Are you sure that works? I don't see anything like it in the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals. It says `interval '3-6' year_month`.

Comment: @Barmar from the docs: `MySQL permits any punctuation delimiter in the expr format. Those shown in the table are the suggested delimiters.` I tried the samples I provided before posting my comment. They work

Comment: @Sentinel Cute. But that also means that order is important, it will treat `P3Y6M` the same as `P3M6Y`, the `M` and `Y` are not interpreted as specifying the units.

Comment: That's true, however, if you switched the order of the delimiters, it wouldn't match the ISO spec any more either.